# How to plot yearly (bar) and monthly (line) time series on same graph with pandas matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframes, one called "*Income*" and one called "*Price*". Sample data is shown below.
*Income* is **annual** data, whereas *Price* is **monthly** data. I would like to plot both series on the same plot with, with *Income*/*Price* on the Y axis.

```
Year,Income
2018,11063
2019,11786
2020,12696
2021,13113
2022,13148
```

```
Month,Price
2021-12-01,92.85
2022-01-01,96.24
2022-02-01,102.75
2022-03-01,113.08
2022-04-01,107.66
```

**What I'm struggling with:**
I can't figure out how to handle the data / plotting, such that I can effectively have 2 x-axis units. In my eye, I'd like my x-axis to be shown like the below. The *Income* data points would be above the "year", and the *Price* datapoints would be above their respective months (which don't necessarily have to be labelled with letters - I've done that for demonstration purposes).

```
J F M A M J¦J A S O N D
| | | | | |¦| | | | | |
           ¦
         2022
```

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this "separate" x-axis behaviour? I thought about putting the yearly *Income* dates as in the month of June or July, so they appear to be more in the middle of the year, and then attempting to style to x-axis to make it appear as I've described. But that wouldn't be entirely correct, so I'm hoping someone has a better solution or advice.

Comment: There is always more than one way to visualize your data. I don't think it make sense to put your yearly and monthly data with different chart types in the same graph.  However, you can try `matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx` and `matplotlib.axes.Axes.twiny`.